# Google Geocoding Limit Reached

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

I am writing some code to geocode a bunch of addresses in a database using curl in the following format:

```
$url . "&address=" . urlencode($school->STREET . " " . $school->TOWN . " " . $school->POSTCODE . " United Kingdom") . "&sensor=false"
```

Now this has been run on 2 different servers. Some addresses run through fine, but others keep giving Limit Reached. How is this possible when the server hasn't requested those addresses yet? And why do some not hit a limit but others do? It makes no sense, surely the limit is not a global one?

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain how they do their limiting, but I suspect they do it by IP address.  Thus, if you have two servers behind a firewall so that they both look like they are coming from the same IP address, Google might block.  Try looking up your IP address from both servers:

Go to:
   http://whatismyipaddress.com/
on each server.  If the IP address is the same, there's your answer.